# wordwrap problems on a webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how do i make sure that on my forum when people submit posts, i do not have this problem of a HUGE unwrapped string as seen on this posting:

[best practice for developing webpage for mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607047/best-practice-for-developing-webpage-for-mobile-phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On StackOverflow you can do it manually like this:

[Here is my link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607047/best-practice-for-developing-webpage-for-mobile-phone)

So potentially you could write a routine that just substitute [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607047/best-practice-for-developing-webpage-for-mobile-phone) as the description, instead of the URL.