# Can I use PHP for a mobi site?

Tags: php, xhtml, mobile

I have been doing some research on mobile websites, and thus far it seems to me that PHP is not supported by most handsets.

I am trying to create multiple form's that lead up to a auto email response, which would be fairly simple if I could use PHP.

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP directly on the handset or are you using it to power a website to be viewed by the handset?

Comment: I am trying to pass form values via POST to PHP functions, so I am trying to use it directly on the handset.

Comment: @kielie: No... you're not. When you submit a form through your mobile handset's browser, the response is sent back to the server as a POST variable. Your *server* then parses this, and the PHP interpreter on your *server* stuffs it into a nice easy to access `$_POST` variable. You have a big misunderstanding here.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, didn't know that, I'm still learning, please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: This is being asked frequently on SO, check the search for previous questions on the issue. A quick search turns up this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607047/best-practice-for-developing-webpage-for-mobile-phone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP is server side language, your server has to be support for it. handsets should support html or whatever you output with php.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is usually executed on the server, not the handset itself, so the question is more if your PHP spits out HTML unsuited for a handset.

Comment: Cool, thanx for the info! It makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - its perfectly possible to write WML using PHP, only vaveat is that you need to add a custom header to set the mimetype if your default behaviour for PHP files is to return text/html. And, of course you need to understand WML - which is quite different from HTML.

These days a lot of handhelds can now cope with HTML although don't expect javascript.

> PHP is not supported by most handsets

Eh? What's that got to do with it? PHP runs on the server - not on the client.

C.

Comment: That is what I read on a few forums actually, no jokes, but now that you've all cleared that up for me, I don't know how the heck they could ever have said something like that, next time I'll just post the question on SO first!

Answer (score 0):

Have a read up on the basic request/response cycle for a web page.

Assuming by "mobile website" you mean "a normal website that is tailored for display on a mobile device" the answer is that PHP runs on the server not the client, the client only displays HTML given to it by the server.

Comment: Yeah basically.
Will do, thanx for the info.